# Finding an integration factor $\mu(xy)$ for first order ODE for a nonexact equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been searching the internet for how to find an integration factor for first order ODE, and I found something, but I didn't quite get the steps for getting what they got. I added a screenshot below. 
I didn't understand how they combined the first to euquations. and the relation between 4th equation and 5th equation. 
I would be grateful for anykind of help! 
here is the full arcticle: 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExactFirst-OrderOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For your fist question, observe that by the chain rule
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=y\,g'(x\,y),\quad\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=x\,g'(x\,y).
$$

To get the fifth equation from the fourth substitute $\dfrac{\partial\mu}{\partial x}$ using the third equation and pass it to the left hand side.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. for my first question I meant how did they combine the first two equations to get the THIRD one.

Comment: I think that the notation used is no very good. Since $g$ depends only on one variable, the partials of $g$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ are the same. The divide one equation by the other.